# Skipping private methods during unit test C#

Tags: c#, unit-testing

```
public bool A (UserRequest foo)
{
    ClientRequest boo = B(foo); //Mapping local model to client model
    C(boo);
    return result;
}
```

I want to write an unit test for method A to test method B but I don't want my unit test to call method C. Method C is a private method but it makes calls to a third party client. I am unable to setup method C in my Unit Test since the type "ClientRequest" doesn't have a reference in the test case assembly. How can this be implemented without adding a reference of the client dll to my test assembly as well. How to skip calling method C ?

Comment: If the goal is to test method B, why not write a unit test that just calls B?

Comment: B is a private method. A is a public method that is exposed as a nuget package. I don't want to mark B as public since it just does the mapping

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> C is a private method

Things are private for a reason.  They are implementation details to which consuming code shouldn't be coupled.  And unit tests are consuming code.

> it makes calls to a third party client

Therein lies the problem with your unit tests.  Don't try to break apart the class being tested, digging into its internals and ultimately modifying what it's doing and as a result invalidating the tests in the first place.

Instead, isolate and mock the dependency.  Somewhere in `C()` this class has an external dependency.  Instead of obscuring that dependency deep within the class, wrap it in an interface/implementation and provide that implementation to the class.  (This is called Dependency Injection.  There are frameworks which provide rich functionality around the concept, but the concept itself can be achieved manually for simple cases as well.)

So when application code uses this class, instances are provided with an implementation of the dependency which calls the external service.  And when unit tests use this class, instances are provided with a mock implementation that pretends to call the external service.

Then your tests can include mocking the results of that service as well, triggering controlled failure responses to test how the class handles them.

Comment: I already thought of this approach. Even if I wrap the third party call inside an interface, how would I pass object "boo" while mocking the interface and setting up the method call ? The test assembly has no idea what "boo" is since its the third party model referenced in the actual project.

Comment: @Sadhurthan: If the type `ClientRequest` is also a dependency then a wrapper for it may need to be part of the mock.  We don't really know anything about your classes and external dependencies, so there's no point in following a rabbit hole one comment at a time.  The main point is that you should encapsulate your dependencies to be mockable to the classes you want to test.  Sometimes it's trivial, sometimes it takes effort.